# Leaving Ph.D due to stipend

Tags: phd, funding, turkey

I am a direct PhD student in Turkey, currently in my third year (of five). Because of the pandemic and the associated sky rocketed inflation in country, I am unable to manage my life with the stipend I get from my PhD. My work is experimental, so going part-time is not really an option. Similarly, transferring to another institution in my country would probably not solve my stipend problem. I asked my supervisor about more funding 1.5 months ago, and he said something would look into it, but no good news yet.

I want to quit PhD and graduate as a Masters student while applying for a PhD position at some place better in terms of stipend. I would need my supervisor's letter of recommendation to secure a new position, so I would need to discuss this with my supervisor before I can begin applying. I am the only one in my group who is facing this decision since the other students are only a year away from graduation (rather than two).

However, I fear that maybe I am doing something wrong and I just need to finish the remaining 2 years time and just obtain my PhD. Is it normal to change universities due to funding issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it happens. I did the same, submitted what would have been my PhD thesis as a Master's thesis, was admitted to another PhD program with a better stipend (albeit more expensive city) and finished. I had no problems gettting postdocs (2) and I'm now a tenured full professor. In my view, switching universities because of funding issues is a much more 'cleaner' way/reason for switching than issues with advisors, labmates, etc. The latter could label you as a problematic student, while (again, in my opinion) funding issues are universal and everybody can understand them.

About your advisor, I can only tell you about my experience. My old advisor was not happy at all with the situation, but also did nothing to help with funding in a meaningful way. I thought he would give me a bad letter of reference, but I guess he must have written a good letter, or that the letters from the other committee members outweighed his letter. I'll never know, but I did get admitted to the other program, which was at a much better university.